Microsoft Graph Batch API fails when sending request within the allowed API Limit
I am currently working on a project where I need to send messages to over 20+ users individually on Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft Graph Batch API [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch]. The Microsoft Graph API to send chat messages to individual users is limited to 20 request per second as per the Microsoft Documentation. Therefore, I created a batch payload of 20 users and used the Microsoft Graph Batch API for sending message to those individual users.
The first batch of 20 messages gets sent successfully, but when I try to send the next batch, I receive an error indicating that the API call quota has been exceeded.
However, after the first batch, If I wait for 8 seconds then the second batch also succeeds else I receive a 429 error.
As per the Microsoft Documentation, I am making the API [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{{chat_unique_id}}/messages] request in the Microsoft Graph Batch API within the specified quota but still receiving a 429.
Is there a some other limitation in the API that I am using to send chat message or is there any limitation in the Batch API?
Is there a way to increase the quota for API calls?
With a delay of 8 seconds between two Microsoft Graph Batch API request, the API request is successful without any failure. The problem is having a delay of 8 seconds is an overhead.

You are breaching how many operations a user can do on the chat (and total number of concurrent operations). So throttling is fully expected. These limits apply to Teams client. There are limits per tenant, per app per tenant, per user, per thread (chat\channel\team). 429 will be hit when one of them is breached.
The limit for the "Send message in a chat" operation (POST /chats/{chat-id}/messages) is 1 message per second.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/throttling-limits

As per the implementation, I am sending message to 40 users in the same tenant. In one batch I am sending 20 request to send message to 20 unique users and in the next batch I am sending message to other 20 unique users and still getting 429. I am sending 1 batch request per second which contains 20 request each. As per the documentation, I am within the allow contain but still getting 429. This is a weird behavior of the API.
I would like to send message to 10,000 users or more and would like to do it within 5-10 minutes or less. Any suggestions would be helpful.
